# Disable 'asset-url' for Compass + Bootstrap SASS style

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, compass-sass, sass

I have an non-ruby project, say just static page, where I want to use Compass + [Twitter Bootstrap SASS](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) for styling.

Btw, Compass generates `css` that have asset functions, like:

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  background-image: asset-url("glyphicons-halflings.png", image);
}
```

As I understand this `asset-url` function should be processed by an RoR post-processor, and I can't use this CSS as is.

I need just:

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  background-image: url("/images/glyphicons-halflings.png");
}
```

Is there any way to configure Compass or Bootstrap SASS to generate valid CSS, w/o any ruby-specific stuff inside?

Comment: Where is that selector coming from?  The only one like that I see in Bootstrap uses the standard `url()`:  https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_sprites.scss

Comment: Hm, that's really strange. I have 'url()' in local gem as well. I thinks it's added by compass

Comment: I found, I had local directory, with an old version of bootstrap scss, I think it shouldn't be unused, but compass uses this directory instead of gem

Comment: Compass prefers a local version over a gem version in the case of duplicates.  Is the gem version included in your config.rb?  You may need to remove the local version all together.

Comment: Yes, i've removed local version (it was just a directory, so didn't think that it going to be used instead of gem) and it helped. I think you can put this as answer here, you helped me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compass prioritizes local versions of code over the gem version, which is great for developing your own extensions (building/installing every time you make a minor change while testing is a bit of a pain).  Removing the local version will allow the gem version to take over.